# django view retrieve all objects of Many-to-Many relationship of foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have three models as following:

```
class Library(models.Model):
    library_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    #This helps to print in admin interface
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.name)

class Book(models.Model):
    book_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # A book can have multiple authors and an author can have multiple books
    author = models.ManyToManyField('Author')

    # A library has many books
    which_library = models.ForeignKey('Library', related_name='books', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    #This helps to print in admin interface
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.title)


class Author(models.Model):
    author_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    #This helps to print in admin interface
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.name)
```

I want to retrieve all authors in a specific library. My view looks like following:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def author_list(request, library_id):
    """
    List all authors in a specific library
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        authors = Author.objects.get()
        serializer = AuthorSerializer(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = AuthorSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

What should I write in get() as my condition?

**UPDATE**: *my logic is*: A library can have many books and a book can have many authors and and an author can have many books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try:

```
authors = Author.objects.filter(book__which_library_id=library_id).distinct()
```

more details in [docs many_to_many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)
(search text article__headline__)

Comment: Thanks! It did work! Could you kindly also explain me what this line does? What this syntax mean?

Comment: glad to help, did you read the documentation by the added link in the answer?

Comment: yea now I found what I was looking for :) thanks a lot!